# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "products_customer"

Tags: python, django

After make migrations , i tried to do migrate, but i am getting the django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "products_customer"

But iam remove this customer table from models.py
how i solve this ?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver



# Create your models here.

class product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_price = models.FloatField()
    product_stock = models.IntegerField()
    product_image = models.CharField(max_length=2500)



class order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    order_total = models.IntegerField()
    order_shipped = models.BooleanField()


class address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    post_office = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    land_mark = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_address(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            address.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_address(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.address.save()
```

Error message

PS C:\Users\sujit\OneDrive\Desktop\project\django> python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
PS C:\Users\sujit\OneDrive\Desktop\project\django> python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, products, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying products.0004_auto_20211114_2342...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "products_customer"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sujit\OneDrive\Desktop\project\django\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\sujit\OneDrive\Desktop\project\django\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
schema_editor.add_field(
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 522, in add_field
self.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "products_customer"

Comment: after `mamemigrations` you digging into migration files to see changes? All looks fine?

Comment: Can you post a full error trace back

Comment: I posted the error message that i get @rahul.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get this error because you try to make the migrations on a non-existent database table.

Try to delete everything from the `migrations` folder (except `__init__.py`), and delete the `.sqlite3` database file as well, then rerun

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

> Be aware, this will delete your database and your migrations so far!

But most likely it will fix your issue.

Comment: here i am using postgresql

Comment: I don't think that changes a lot, you just need to reset the database.